# checking if a letter is present in a string in python

Tags: python

How can I check if the letter "N" is present in a string.
Example:

```
flag = False
if string contains N:
   flag = True
```

So `flag = True` if string is `"CNDDDNTD"` and `flag = False` if string is `"CCGGTTT"`. I think re.search will work, but not sure of the options to use.

Comment: `"N" in mystring` ?

Comment: `'N' in 'CNDDDNTD'` returns True, `'N' in 'CCGGTTT'` returns False

Comment: You can do ``flag = "n" in string or "N" in string`` in just one line.

Answer (score 13):

```
>>> 'N' in 'PYTHON'
True
>>> 'N' in 'STACK OVERFLOW'
False
>>> 'N' in 'python' # uppercase and lowercase are not equal
False
>>> 'N' in 'python'.upper()
True
```

Also, there is no need for a conditional statement when assigning to your `flag`.  Rather than

```
flag = False
if 'N' in your_string:
   flag = True
```

do

```
flag = 'N' in your_string
```